# Colourful Candy Cane Carousel

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This is part 2 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Deаr Puzzling,

Today I walked in an unbelievable tropical palm forest. I have seen black parrots, weird lizards, and frogs climbing on trees growing the biggest coconuts I have ever seen.

Today’s puzzle is hexagonal cryptic crossword. “Around” clues form a clockwise spiral starting at the number 1 on the left-hand side of the grid. “Candy cane” clues start from the numbered cell and follow the coloured squares across the grid, each including the purple central cell and continuing on the other side. Answers are placed in the order given, one after the other, with no spaces. Answer lengths have been omitted.

There are two sets of clues for each candy cane colour. One set produces the correct answers, which must be written in the grid; the other clue set produces wrong answers where only *some* of the letters match the rest of the answers. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2powc8r6)

**1. Around**
a) Scratch the surface of legislation behind the principle of consent
b) The hero in William Shakespeare's work *Julius Caesar* was born here the first of October
c) Fresh avocados kept in disorder
d) Edward I's about face
e) Fantasy monster's makin' turkey-like sounds that we hear
f) Stylish bird seen near Kentucky
g) Unit of measurement used in the UK, and in the US, and in Switzerland
h) Trick performed by skateboarder Stan's partner
i) Bare grassland
j) Norwegian pop group filled with energy and emboldened, finally getting forward
k) Health resort in a place where the rain stays mainly in the 1i?
l) Atkinson's character has soy and coffee?
m) Hot drink by Norway's first Starbucks, perhaps
n) Woman depicted in Disney film (mostly from behind) has suddenly cleared out psychiatric facility
o) Young animal (a little rodent) trapped by molten rock
p) Husky is an animal familiar to the Mongols, reportedly
q) Was Satan brought back?
r) Attach previous résumé at the back

**2. Yellow candy cane**
OPTION A
a) Many an obstruction was pierced by pair of drills
b) Bother Adam's wife after gym class
c) Religious group obstinately denies libelling youth leaders
OPTION B
d) Custody has liberal character
e) Student neglected to acquire information and make money
f) Gladys meeting with narcos to show plan

**3. Blue candy cane**
OPTION A
a) Red-coloured rims stolen by criminal
b) The cleric mistakenly evicted the leader of heathens making use of an invisible force of nature
OPTION B
c) Problem on a desert: Holding on to things to drink
d) Body part of very real birds oddly not taken into consideration

**4. Red candy cane**
OPTION A
a) Olivia and Diana about to be very angry
b) Tailor being interrupted by West ultimately leads to commotion
c) Unexpectedly mutual component of Motörhead
OPTION B
d) It conquers all or nothing at Wimbledon
e) Comedian Bob who appeared in numerous films – he has taken on work
f) Part of a classical orchestra: "During concert, I'm panicking"

---

Gladys will return in *[Mazed and Confused](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119043/41973)*.

Comment: Shameless self-plug for people who struggle to make sense of this type of puzzles: I've made a YouTube tutorial ([part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkYt3g9WJvY), [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir_IJLjl0f0)) for total beginners explaining how to solve cryptic crosswords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gladys is visiting:

> the [**Vallée de Mai**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vall%C3%A9e_de_Mai) Nature Reserve in the Seychelles!
>
>  This answer is found by extracting the letters that are common to each candy cane option, reading down and across the completed grid. These letters are written in blue in the image below.

The completed grid:

> [image: Completed grid]

Clue explanations (correct enumerations added, mainly to help break up the clue and answer within the text):

> **1. Around**
>  a) **Scratch** the surface of legislation behind the principle of consent (4) **CLAW** = C(-onsent) + LAW (legislation)
>  b) **The hero in William Shakespeare's work** Julius Caesar was born here the first of October (5) **ROMEO** = ROME (Julius Caesar w as born here) + O_
>  c) Fresh avocados kept in **disorder** (5) **HAVOC** = _H AVOC_
>  d) Edward I's about **face** (4) **SIDE** = (ED I’S)<
>  e) **Fantasy monster**'s makin' turkey-like sounds that we hear (6) **GOBLIN** = “GOBBLIN’”
>  f) **Stylish** bird seen near Kentucky (6) **SWANKY** = SWAN (bird) +KY (Kentucky)
>  g) **Unit of measurement used in the UK, and in the US**, and in Switzerland (4) **INCH** = IN + CH (Switzerland)
>  h) **Trick performed by skateboarder** / **Stan's partner** (5) **[OLLIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_and_Hardy)** = ddef
>  i) **Bare** / **grassland** (5) **PLAIN** = ddef
>  j) Norwegian pop group filled with energy and emboldened, finally getting **forward** (5) **AHEAD** = [AHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-ha) containing E (energy) + (-emboldene)D
>  k) Health resort in **a place where the rain stays mainly in the [plain]?** (5) **[SPAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rain_in_Spain)** = SPA + IN
>  l) Atkinson's character has **soy and coffee?** (5) **BEANS** = [BEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bean)’S
>  m) Hot drink by Norway's first **Starbucks, perhaps** (5) **CHAIN** = CHAI (Hot drink) + N(-orway)
>  n) Woman depicted in Disney film (mostly from behind) has suddenly cleared out **psychiatric facility** (6) **ASYLUM** = MULA(-n)< containing S_Y
>  o) **Young animal** (a little rodent) trapped by molten rock (5) **LARVA** = LA(R_)VA
>  p) **Husky** is an animal familiar to the Mongols, reportedly (6) **HOARSE** = “HORSE”
>  q) **Was** Satan brought back? (5) **LIVED** = DEVIL<
>  r) **Attach** previous résumé at the back (5) **PASTE** = PAST (previous) + (-resum)E
>
>  **2. Yellow candy cane**
>  OPTION A
>  a) **Many an obstruction** was pierced by pair of drills (5) **WALLS** = WA((-dri)LL(-s))S
>  b) **Bother** Adam's wife after gym class (5) **PEEVE** = PE (gym class) + EVE (Adam’s wife)
>  c) **Religious** group obstinately denies libelling youth leaders (5) **GODLY** = G_ O_ D_ L_ Y_
>  OPTION B
>  d) Custody has liberal **character** (7) **CALIBRE** = CA(LIB)RE
>  e) Student neglected to acquire information and make money (4) **EARN** = (-l)EARN
>  f) Gladys meeting with narcos to show **plan** (4) **IDEA** = I (Gladys) + [DEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_Enforcement_Administration) (narcos)
>
>  **3. Blue candy cane**
>  OPTION A
>  a) **Red-coloured** rims stolen by criminal (7) **CRIMSON** = C(RIMS)ON
>  b) The cleric mistakenly evicted the leader of heathens making use of **an invisible force of nature** (8) **ELECTRIC** = T(-h)ECLERIC*
>  OPTION B
>  c) Problem on a desert: Holding on to **things to drink** (9) **LEMONADES** = _LEM ON A DES_
>  d) **Body part** of very real birds oddly not taken into consideration (6) **EYELID** = _E_Y _E_L _I_D_
>
>  **4. Red candy cane**
>  OPTION A
>  a) Olivia and Diana about to be **very angry** (5) **LIVID** = LIV + DI<
>  b) Tailor being interrupted by West ultimately leads to **commotion** (4) **STEW** = S(_T)EW
>  c) Unexpectedly mutual **component of Motörhead** (6) **UMLAUT** = MUTUAL*
>  OPTION B
>  d) **It conquers all** or **nothing at Wimbledon** (4) **LOVE** = cdef + cdef
>  e) **Comedian Bob who appeared in numerous films** – he has taken on work (4) **[HOPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Hope)** = H(OP)E
>  f) **Part of a classical orchestra**: "During concert, I'm panicking" (7) **TIMPANI** = _T IM PANI_

So extracting the answer:

> Yellow: W[A][L]LSP[E][E]VEGO[D]LY vs C[A][L]IBR[E][E]ARNI[D]EA
>
>  Blue: CRIMSON[E]L[E]CTR[I]C vs LEMONAD[E]S[E]YEL[I]D
>
>  Red: [L]I[V]IDST[E]WU[M]L[A]UT vs [L]O[V]EHOP[E]TI[M]P[A]NI
>
>  Reading these letters off in the order seen in the completed grid produces VALLEE DE MAI.

Comment: Ah dangit, I was so close! :P ROT13(V bayl unq 3n yrsg juvpu V pbhyqa'g svther bhg... V rira gubhtug bs pevzvany orvat pba ohg V sbetbg gb gel gur cbffvovyvgl bs evzf orvat whfg cynvagrkg!)

Comment: @oAlt Oof, sorry! Was in the cryptic zone this morning. 1a was the last one I found, and it took me a long while for 1r to click. I had to construct the crossword using overlaps with known candy cane common letters - the long way round! :)

Comment: Ah, nice :) (I also forgot to mention that though I also found the answer to 1n, I never really figured out the wordplay.)