# Hippos and Horseplay

Tags: knowledge, chess, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 5 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Deаr Puzzling,

This time you are going to need some of your chess knowledge. Not a *lot* of chess knowledge, though – you simply need to know how a single piece moves! Find a path for a knight starting in the lower left corner to cover each unshaded cell exactly once, ending in the cell marked with the white diamond. The grid is eight by eight, because a chessboard has eight lines and eight files and the number eight is significant.

Today I have visited a national park that’s bigger than many countries and seen lions, hippos and giraffes in their natural environment. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty grid]
[Crossword on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2egy9rsn)
[Knight’s tour on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2nyl7nfs) (use the “line / free” mode)

**Across**
1. Artists who sing "All Along the Watchtower", "Turn the Page" and "Jammin'", for example
4. A letter used in the names of Corfu, Cyprus and Crete
7. Automatic weapons from 10 down
8. A coastal inlet
9. A Pacific island nation
11. A novel by Jane Austen
13. An official language of South Africa
15. A Starfleet officer
17. An Indian king or prince
18. A shah of Iran
19. A type of small deer native to Eurasia
20. An aircraft or ship's personnel
21. A person like Forrest Gump or Doctor Dolittle
22. A disease the Berlin Patient was famously cured of *(abbr.)*

**Down**
1. An enthusiast or expert
2. A small jewel
3. Antebellum
5. A relative of Muhammad's on his father's side
6. Animal cells that can be fertilised
10. A name given to Jacob
12. Allocated portion
14. A language spoken in the Caucasus
16. A thriller film by Steven Spielberg
17. Accelerate without the gears engaged

---

Gladys will return in *[Who’s in for a Cruising?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119301/41973)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gladys is at

> [**Ruaha National Park**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruaha_National_Park) in **Tanzania.**

The answer to the crossword is as follows:

> [image: crossword]

**Across**

> 1. Artists who sing "All Along the Watchtower"(*Bob Dylan*), "Turn the Page"(*Bob Seger*) and "Jammin'"(*Bob Marley*), for example -> **BOBS**
> 4. A letter used in the names of Corfu(*Κέρκυρα*), Cyprus(*Κύπρος*) and Crete(*Κρήτη*)  -> ρ-**RHO**
> 7. Automatic weapons from 10 down (*Israel*) -> **UZIS**
> 8. A coastal inlet -> **RIA**
> 9. A Pacific island nation -> **FIJI**
> 11. A novel by Jane Austen -> **EMMA**
> 13. An official language of South Africa -> **SWAZI**
> 15. A Starfleet officer -> **UHURA**
> 17. An Indian king or prince -> **RAJA**
> 18. A shah of Iran -> **REZA**
> 19. A type of small deer native to Eurasia -> **ROE**
> 20. An aircraft or ship's personnel -> **CREW**
> 21. A person like Forrest Gump or Doctor Dolittle -> **VET**
> 22. A disease the Berlin Patient was famously cured of *(abbr.)* -> **AIDS**

**Down**

> 1. An enthusiast or expert -> **BUFF**
> 2. A small jewel -> **BIJOU**
> 3. Antebellum -> **PREWAR**
> 5. A relative of Muhammad's on his father's side -> **HAMZA**
> 6. Animal cells that can be fertilised -> **OVA**
> 10. A name given to Jacob -> **ISRAEL**
> 12. Allocated portion -> **SHARE**
> 14. A language spoken in the Caucasus -> **AZERI**
> 16. A thriller film by Steven Spielberg -> **JAWS**
> 17. Accelerate without the gears engaged -> **REV**

And the Knight's Tour is as follows:

> [image: Knight's Tour-animation]
>   <sup>(*Click to see the static version*)</sup>

Then,

> Reading the letters along the Knight's path gives a string which makes no sense. Then we notice Gladys saying in her letter "*the number eight is significant*", so we extract the letters in positions within periods of 8-letters (starting from 9th, ignoring the initial position)
>
> ```
> VAFZSIOM [R] VZAEERS [U] BIPAAJE [A] ARUIBIF [H] EYCZSRH [A] AWI
> ```
>
> and those letters spell where she is.