# Who’s in for a Cruising?

Tags: knowledge, grid-deduction, geography, crosswords, limerick

<sub>This is part 6 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Deаr Puzzling,

Looks like I’m getting way behind schedule already. Sorry about that! Time flies when you’re having fun, which I definitely am. Don’t worry, I’ll try to catch up in the coming weeks! The goal is still a new puzzle every Saturday.

This one is a mid-loop puzzle. Draw a loop that passes through all the black circles in the grid, going horizontally or vertically through centres of cells without crossing itself or branching out. Each black circle must be in the middle of the straight segment that passes through it. For example, if the loop goes straight for three cells before passing through the circle, it must continue straight for three cells in the other direction and then turn. In the finished grid, start from the leftmost column and follow the loop clockwise, reading every letter that has a black circle entirely in its cell.

Today I have boarded a historic passenger ferry to explore the shores of a major body of water. Hopefully in schedule, but with my track record, maybe I can’t expect much... Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword/mid-loop grid]
[Crossword on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2gflx6m6)
[Mid-loop on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2kucc3oh)

**Across**
1. Did injure another by hitting with blade
5. As if in the manner of one who's health's frayed
6. Like males, to the utmost
8. This means "first and foremost" (5,3)

**Down**
1. It's one way to move on a snow-covered glade
2. The first name of Catholic head named de Borgia
3. A jelly-filled treat for a sweet dessert gorger
4. Dried lentil or pea
6. Lunch, breakfast or tea
7. Traditional lard from Ukraine (west of Georgia)

---

Gladys will return in *[Kings of Centuries Past](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119360/41973)*.

Comment: +1, but I think the meter is off and it should be: Did injure another with blade/ In the manner of one whose health's frayed / … / To move on a snow-covered glade / The first name of pope named de Borgia / A jelly-filled treat for a gorger / … / Lard from Ukraine (west of Georgia)

Comment: @msh210 Counting is hard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Crossword solution:

> [image: crossword grid; words STABBED, INFIRMLY, MANLIEST, ABOVE ALL / SKI, ALFONSO, BERLINER, DAL, MEAL, SALO]

Mid-loop solution:

> Some starting deductions:
>  [image: grid 1]
>
>  Next, the segment at R5C3 can't go right, or it would need to be extended into two dots in a row. Similar "don't put two dots on one line" logic can be used after that to get this far:
>  [image: grid 2]
>
>  Continuing...
>  [image: grid 3]
>
>  Here, R2C4 must be extended; from this, the puzzle can be finished.
>  [image: final grid]

Following the instructions, the indicated letters spell

> [image: overlaid grids]
>
>  [**MV LIEMBA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MV_Liemba), a passenger ferry that runs in Lake Tanganyika.

Comment: And there was me expecting the answer to be LIMERICK :)

Comment: @Stiv limerick is in the clues.

Comment: @ACB Indeed - I didn't want Jafe's clever construction to go unnoticed :)