# In Remembrance of Dark Times

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords, printers-devilry

<sub>This is part 8 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Deаr Puzzling,

The name of the game here is printer’s devilry, with an added definition part in each clue. In each clue, you must find a single nine-letter word which can be inserted somewhere into the clue (possibly changing spacing, punctuation and capitalisation but not the order of letters) so that the whole sentence makes sense. Some part of the clue (not necessarily at the start or end) also acts as a straight crossword definition for the answer.

After solving the clues, insert the answers into the grid starting from the numbered cell in the top row and going downwards. Words do not have to be in a straight line and can make turns, but together they must fill up the entire grid. The answer is two symmetrical words.

Today I have visited a historic building which now functions as a reminder of the gruesome practices this part of the world was long subjected to. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2paptydf)

**Printer’s devilry clues**
1. "I haven't capitalised much on the precint's new coffee machine", the detective said. "On principle, I only drink one CI solve." (9)
2. The people calling for stricter background checks have not folded their cards yet and are pressing on with their ant IG. "Bundy would have no trouble getting his hands on weapons here", the group's representative was quoted as saying. (9)
3. My train passes through the Baltics and soon I'll have everyone Pam, Tonia's finest spa resort! (9)
4. I have a strong dislike for cheese products from Maricopa County, especially sub tilt ons.
5. An overheated Apple computer started a fire at the airport which turned the TA rim, mering piles of ash. (9)
6. The Marxist country of Cuba is an independent nation, sit in its World Factbook. (9)
7. Noam Chomsky was showing indications of being glad, T? Oui! St. Student's yearbook. (9)
8. A fan gave Richard Petty a flower and called him the best driver inn as wide. (9)
9. The soldier we interviewed has great abilities relating to large-scale military plans and everyone is saying he's a fir. An we discuss hiring him? (9)

---

Gladys will return in *[The Key to the City](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119526/41973)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are in

> Ghana

visiting

> Elmina Castle, closely associated with the abominable *slave trade*.

PD solutions:

> 1. "I haven't *capitalised* much on the precint's new coffee machine", the detective said. "On principle, I only drink one C[UPPERCASE]I solve." (9)
> 2. The people calling for stricter background checks have *not folded* their cards yet and are pressing on with their ant IG[UNPLEATED]. "Bundy would have no trouble getting his hands on weapons here", the group's representative was quoted as saying. (9)
> 3. My train *passes through* the Baltics and soon I'll have everyone Pam[PERMEATES]Tonia's finest spa resort! (9)
> 4. I have a strong dislike for *cheese products* from Maricopa County, especially sub[PARMESANS]tilt ons. (9)
> 5. An overheated *Apple computer* started a fire at the airport which turned the TA r[MACINTOSH]im, mering piles of ash. (9)
> 6. The *Marxist* country of Cuba is an independent nation, [SOCIALIST]sit in its World Factbook. (9)
> 7. Noam Chomsky was *showing indications of* being glad, T? O[SIGNALING]ui! St. Student's yearbook. (9)
> 8. A fan gave Richard Petty a *flower* and called him the best driver inn as[CARNATION]wide. (9)
> 9. The soldier we interviewed has great abilities *relating to large-scale military plans* and everyone is saying he's a fir[STRATEGIC]An we discuss hiring him? (9)

Completed grid (the process of completion is not so difficult, given the answers, as to need documenting step by step):

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> u u p p m s s c s
>  p n e a o i a t
>   p p r c g r r
>    e l m i n a
>     r e n a t
>    c a S t l e
>   a t a o I i g
>  s e n s N o s i
> e s D s h g n T c
>
> 1 3 2 4 5 7 8 6 9
> ```

And then

> in the two rows on either side of the middle, we see ELMINA CASTLE.

Comment: (In case anyone cares: I did not look at ralphmerridew's answer before posting mine.)

Answer (score -1):

> 1.  cUP PER CASE i solve
>   5.  tarMAC INTO SHimmering
>   8.  in nasCAR NATIONwide
>   9.  firST RATE GI. Can

Comment: (https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6705/partial-answers-and-list-of-clues-puzzles)