# Round and Round (the World)

Tags: knowledge, rhyme, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 17 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Deаr Puzzling,

Today’s puzzle is a circular crossword with overlapping answers. Answers in all directions can share any number of letters with the preceding answer, and *must* share at least one. Answer lengths have been given, but keep in mind that these are standard crossword clues, not cryptic clues this time. “Around” clues go clockwise from the numbered cell onwards, in the order given. “Inward” clues are given out of order and you must determine yourself to which column each answer belongs, as well as in what position that answer is in its column. One “inward” answer does not fit anywhere in the grid; this answer tells you what part of the “inward” answers, when read in the correct order, gives the final answer.

Today I have admired the view over a major city from an iconic old building dedicated to science. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

PS. The solve link takes you to a rectangular grid because Penpa+ doesn’t support circular grids. Just think of it as wrapping around from the right-hand edge and continuing on the same row on the left-hand side. I hope it’s not too confusing!

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2lyk7beo)

**Around**
6a. I am the name of Saint with "fire"; one who you can tickle (4)
6b. A group of birds which man's arrival placed in quite a pickle (4)
6c. Some snakes just like the one that caused the death of Egypt's queen (4)
6d. Attach two pieces of some fabric, stitches in-between (3)
7a. A choice that's picked beforehand; value in advance assigned (6)
7b. The school of more PMs than Harrow, Westminster combined (4)
7c. This means the same as "86" (and those words also rhyme) (3)
8a. A stretch of water – there were seven during Sinbad's time (3)
8b. A bride is walked by father down this, under people's gaze (5)
8c. She can be seen in *Hateful Eight* (a couple of different ways) (5)
9a. These, lots of these – what Neo needed on the silver screen (4)
9b. Disparaging, derisive, nasty, hateful, cruel and mean (5)
9c. A large and horned game animal that sounds like John (the tractor) (4)

**Inward**
1–5a. A social role, appearance, or a part played by an actor (7)
1–5b. The 1990 follow-up to *Operation: Mindcrime* (6)
1–5c. A porch with roof in open air a house has on the outside (7)
1–5d. The drugs that make you active – ones like "E" but unlike codeine (6)
1–5e. Destructive frenzy, blowup, spree of violence that's exploding (7)
1–5f. A track that's on this album: "Little Rock" by Collin Raye (8)
1–5g. The types of creatures that Tanjiro must set off to slay (6)
1–5h. Elizabeth II had the longest in her land (5)
1–5i. Field worker with the likes of which the CIA is manned (5)
1–5j. This motion picture brought an Oscar to one named Charlize (7)
1–5k. On no occasion! Not a chance! At no time! By no means! (5)

---

Gladys will return in *[Sneaks and Addlers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/120316/41973)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Completed grid:

> [image: Completed Crossword Grid]

6a.

> [ELMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Elmo%27s_fire) and [ELMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickle_Me_Elmo)

6b.

> [MOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moa)

6c.

> [ASPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra)

6d.

> SEW

7a.

> PRESET

7b.

> [ETON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eton_College)

7c.

> NIX

8a.

> SEA

8b.

> AISLE

8c.

> LEIGH (_l eigh_, also [Jennifer Jason Leigh](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3460252/))

9a.

> GUNS

9b.

> SNIDE

9c.

> [DEER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Deere)

Inward
1–5a.

> PERSONA Column 2

1–5b.

> EMPIRE Column 5

1–5c.

> VERANDA Column 3

1–5d.

> UPPERS Column 2

1–5e.

> RAMPAGE Column 1

1–5f.

> EXTREMES Column ?

1–5g.

> DEMONS Column 4

1–5h.

> REIGN Column 5

1–5i.

> AGENT Column 1

1–5j.

> MONSTER Column 4

1–5k.

> NEVER Column 3

Which gives us:

> EXTREMES as the hint for which letters in each column to read, and we do so to get: [RUNDETAARN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rundetaarn)