# Layers upon Layers

Tags: knowledge, grid-deduction, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 19 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

This time I have a Suraromu puzzle for you. The grid contains seven “gates”, marked by dotted lines. Draw one continuous loop through unshaded cells which passes through every gate exactly once. The loop must pass through the centre of any cell it enters, and must enter and leave any such cell horizontally or vertically through the edges. It can't cross itself or branch out. The loop starts and ends at the cell containing the circled number 7. Some gates are numbered; this number indicates the position of that gate in the entire loop in one direction. For example, if a gate has the number 2, it has to be the second gate visited by the loop. The direction in which the loop is traversed can be either clockwise or anticlockwise, but all gates must be numbered according to the same direction.

Today I am visiting a destination where I have to wear a few layers more than in my previous stops. I have to say the mountain views here are spectacular. I can by no means cover the entire place on one visit as it is a huge area, albeit unfortunately diminishing year by year because of us humans. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty suraromu/crossword grid]
[Crossword on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2yl59u6a)
[Suraromu on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2ae79h5k)

**Across**
1. The first name of two of a king's six wives
3. A hybrid animal
5. Language branch that includes Arabic and Hebrew
6. Public show of respect
10. Hawaiian dance
11. Back of the neck
13. She was turned into a tree
14. Stigmatised Catholic friar
15. Prominent bodily feature of King Midas
16. Dutch retailer chain

**Down**
1. A European capital is named after her
2. Fictional submarine captain
3. Power, strength
4. City near the French-Belgian border
7. Rush headlong
8. Sub-Saharan African currency
9. High-ranking faculty members
12. Political party official

---

Gladys will return in *[Singles, Doubles, Triples](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/120517/41973)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gladys is at...

> The **Aletsch Glacier**.

First...

> We can solve the Suraromu and the crossword independently.
>  [image: Suraromu Solution]
>  [image: Crossword Solution]

Then...

> We can highlight all the white cells unused by the Suraromu path, and overlay those cells on the crossword grid.
>  [image: Suraromu Solution Highlighted]
>  [image: Crossword Solution Highlighted]

Finally...

> We can read out the letters from the highlighted cells on the crossword grid to get the answer of **ALETSCH GLACIER**.