# In It for the Long Haul

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, grid-deduction, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 22 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

The light grey numbers and arrows from a Yajilin puzzle. Shade some cells in the grid and draw one continuous loop that visits all unshaded cells, except those that have numbers in them, going horizontally and vertically through centres of cells without crossing itself or branching out. Shaded cells cannot share an edge with another shaded cell, but they can touch numbered cells. In each numbered cell, the number indicates how many shaded cells are in the direction of the arrow.

In the crossword, you have three options for each answer. Fill the grid by selecting one answer for each clue from the options provided.

Travelling here was the longest single stretch so far this trip. I suppose when you travel as much as I do, you have to get used to the occasional long-haul flight. Today I am at a public square in the centre of a large city. I have visited a beautiful cathedral and admired the numerous statues, monuments and fountains in the surrounding area. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty Yajilin/crossword grid]
[Yajilin on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2bbcg8wo) (no answer check)
[Crossword on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2bbbqfog)

**Across**
1. MAIDEN / PIPE UP / TAKE IN
6. FILM NOIR / PARAMOUR / PARANOIA
10. STEALING / TRAMPLED / TREKKING
12. MARGINAL / NECKWEAR / NUISANCE
17. ATHEISTS / ATOMISED / BROTHERS
18. ELBOWS / EXETER / YOUTHS

**Down**
2. ALE / ART / IRE
3. IMAM / KANA / PALM
4. DNA / EMO / END
5. NUANCE / PIANOS / PINEAL
6. FAT / PET / PUS
7. ODIN / OGLE / OVEN
8. ADD / RAG / RED
9. CREATE / FRUITY / GRUDGE
11. ACEH / ARCH / ECHO
12. NBA / NFL / MLB
13. IBIS / WAIT / WARS
14. LAB / RED / RUS
15. ASH / DEE / LEW
16. FEW / USE / SEE

---

Gladys will return in *[Tetromino Jigsaw Madness](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/120744/41973)*.

Comment: If anyone is interested how Gladys's trip so far looks on the map, I have the destinations plotted at https://jafe.travelmap.net/. That page is updated a little behind on purpose (currently up to part 19), but should give at least some indication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gladys is in

> São Paolo, Brazil

The Yajilin solves like this:

> [image: Solved Yajilin]

And the crossword like this:

> 15/17/18 can only be DEE/ATHEISTS/EXETER, and from there extends a chain to fill in the board entirely as so: [image: Solved Crossword]

The inbounds shaded squares of the Yajilin overlay onto the crossword to highlight the letters

> P R A C A D A S E

Which convert to

> [Praça da Sé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pra%C3%A7a_da_S%C3%A9)