# Changing Landscape

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords, crosswords

<sub>This is part 24 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

Today I am at a place high up in the mountains that I would have loved to visit 20 or 30 years ago. The views from up here are still breathtaking, but the glacier that once covered this area is now gone forever. Definitely still worth the visit, and it has been on my bucket list for a long time now. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Two empty crossword grids side by side, one labelled "Cryptic" and the other "Straight"]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2ge5vm3n)

**Cryptic across**
2. Cancels hospital drama (6)
7. Law-enforcing northerners' facial hair disentangles (8)
9. Some extremists deserted Greek city-state (4)
10. Right-wingers to consume large and small fish (3)
11. The eighth letter of alphabet starting in "alpha" (5)
12. Claws inflict pain upon cutting Poles (5)
15. Utter insanity – all pieces of tin scrapped (3)
16. 10 down of US produced meth? (4)
18. Container associated with Nazis holds sexy pics (8)
19. Male predator backed by personal label (6)

**Cryptic down**
1. Unit of military police pursuing mafia's second most prominent member (3)
3. Copper left in boxing arena: "This is an Olympic sport!" (7)
4. State university north of Panama maybe brought up (4)
5. Rear end Euro vehicle (4)
6. Go south of Tennessee (southern state) (5)
8. Following departure of head of sales, CEO's wish: high performance (3,4)
10. Rival cavalrymen emptied up pockets (5)
13. Nevermind, perhaps Bob's beginning to escape compound with Al (4)
14. Final 9 across of *Dracula's Tango* (4)
17. Ms Newton and Mr Gates's company launched this web portal in 1995 (3, *abbr.*)

**Straight across**
2. Small bushes
7. Canadian coppers
9. Role, position
10. Fish which can be electric
11. Greek letter
12. Metal fasteners
15. Sylvester Stallone
16. Sound of clearing throat
18. Prisoner photos
19. Record label from Michigan

**Straight down**
1. Piece of guitar equipment
3. Gaelic sport
4. The Home of Jazz?
5. Religious group
6. Written treatise
8. Spectacle on skates (3,4)
10. Bowel cleanse
13. Potassium aluminium sulphate
14. Endure, survive
17. Place to access Hotmail and Messenger, say (*abbr.*)

---

Gladys will return in *[Ticking Off Boxes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121146/41973)*.

Comment: 11A in the cryptic is GORGEOUS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finished grid(s):

> [image: both filled out crossword grids]

We'll start with the straight crossword answers:

> **Straight across**
>  2. Small bushes - SHRUBS
>  7. Canadian coppers - MOUNTIES
>  9. Role, position - PART
>  10. Fish which can be electric - EEL
>  11. Greek letter - THETA
>  12. Metal fasteners - NAILS
>  15. Sylvester Stallone - SLY
>  16. Sound of clearing throat - AHEM
>  18. Prisoner photos - MUGSHOTS
>  19. Record label from Michigan - MOTOWN
>
>  **Straight down**
>  1. Piece of guitar equipment - AMP
>  3. Gaelic sport - HURLING
>  4. The Home of [Jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_Jazz)? - UTAH
>  5. Religious group - SECT
>  6. Written treatise - ESSAY
>  8. Spectacle on skates (3,4) - ICE SHOW
>  10. Bowel cleanse - ENEMA
>  13. Potassium aluminium sulphate - ALUM
>  14. Endure, survive - LAST
>  17. Place to access Hotmail and Messenger, say (abbr.) - MSN

And now the cryptic ones:

> **Cryptic across**
>  2. **Cancels** | **hospital drama** (6) - SCRUBS ddef
>  7. **Law-enforcing northerners**' facial hair disentangles (8) - MO UNTIES
>  9. **Some** extremists deserted Greek city-state (4) - (-s)PART(-a)
>  10. Right-wingers to consume large and small **fish** (3) - _E \E \L
>  11. **The eighth letter of alphabet starting in "alpha"** (5) - THE _T A_ &lit!
>  12. **Claws** inflict pain upon cutting Poles (5) - N(AIL)S
>  15. **Utter** insanity – all pieces of tin scrapped (3) - (-in)SA(-nit)Y
>  16. **10 down of US** produced meth? (4) - THEM*
>  18. Container associated with Nazis holds sexy **pics** (8) - MUG + S(HOT)S
>  19. Male predator backed by personal **label** (6) - MOT< OWN
>
>  **Cryptic down**
>  1. **Unit** of military police pursuing mafia's second most prominent member (3) - _A_ MP
>  3. Copper left in boxing arena: **"This is an Olympic sport!"** (7) - CU R(L)ING
>  4. **State** university north of Panama maybe brought up (4) - U_ TAH<
>  5. **Rear end** | **[Euro vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEAT)** (4) - SEAT ddef
>  6. **Go** south of Tennessee (southern state) (5) - _E S SAY
>  8. Following departure of head of sales, CEO's wish: high **performance** (3,4) - ICESHOW(-s_)
>  10. **Rival** cavalrymen emptied up pockets (5) - _E NEMY_
>  13. Nevermind, perhaps Bob's beginning to escape **compound with Al** (4) - AL(-b_)UM
>  14. **Final 9 across** of Dracula's Tango (4) - _LA'S T_
>  17. Ms Newton and **Mr Gates's company launched this web portal in 1995** (3, abbr.) - MS N

Wow, a lot of these answers are

> the same! Or at least, very similar.

Maybe we should

> highlight the letters that are different:
>
>  [image: the grids again, with the letters that are different between the two grids highlighted]

Now we can clearly see that Gladys is in

> **[Chacaltaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chacaltaya), in Bolivia!**