# Ticking Off Boxes

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This is part 25 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

This is a Y’s Are Wild crossword. That means any instances of the letter Y in the grid are to be treated as wildcards that do not need to match the corresponding letter in the checking answer. (For answer check, omit the Y and write just the checking letter in the grid.)

Today I have ticked off another long-awaited box from my lengthy list of places to visit, and travelled to see the ruins of an ancient fortress high up in the mountains. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2ap6fmsw)

**Across**
1. The King given a Rolls Royce, perhaps? (3)
3. Trainee started a Caesarean section the wrong way (5)
7. Retired British doctor's behind the onset of uncurable disease (4)
8. Framed, uncoloured, round piece is a type of painting (4)
11. 18+ rating nixed from *Radio X*, one of Foxx's pix (3)
12. Doomed characters featured in tragedy in Greece (5)
13. Tech company's info about adversaries (5)
14. Picked up composer's watch (3)
17. Youth organisation for Christian men and other people (4)
18. Smart programmers have, for decades, used this old programming language, eschewing the predecessor of C (4)
19. Left-wingers in congress in Riverside, Ca. and Anaheim, Ca. (5)
20. Gladys's against power and force of evil (3)

**Down**
1. Citizen of EU country discontented – mounting pressure to take to the streets (7)
2. Images of him can be seen all over Egypt, topped with gold and spiritual energy (4)
3. *Con Air* actor John almost has led production to an impasse (3-2-3)
4. Short follower of the Church of England embraces English woman (8)
5. Lone Star State tech company stopped payments? Those are obligatory! (6)
6. State capital, as previously known (3)
9. Empty inside, Eddy drinks large cocktail with great appetite (7)
10. Club for introduction to polka, say (6)
15. Maybe men's moustaches starting to appear in an ominous manner (4)
16. Swiss knife peeled twofold letter (3)

---

Gladys will return in *[Protected Schooling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121196/41973)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gladys traveled to

> [**Kuélap**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku%C3%A9lap)**!**

Solved crossword (for letters that conflict with a Y, the letter belonging to the across entry is at the left):

> [image: solved crossword]

Clue explanations:

**Across**

> 1. The King given a Rolls Royce, perhaps? (3)
>  **CAR** (Rolls Royce perhaps) = CR (the King, Charles III) given A
>
>  3. Trainee started a Caesarean section the wrong way (5)
>  **CADET** (trainee) = star(TED A C)aesarean section, reversed (the wrong way)
>
>  7. Retired British doctor's behind the onset of uncurable disease (4)
>  **KURU** (disease) = reversed (retired) UK (British) + _R (doctor's behind) + U_ (the onset of uncurable)
>
>  8. Framed, uncoloured, round piece is a type of painting (4)
>  **NUDE** (a type of painting) = fram(ED UN)coloured reversed (round) piece
>
>  11. 18+ rating nixed from Radio X, one of Foxx's pix (3)
>  **RAY** (one of Foxx's pix (motion pictures); 2004 film) = X (18+ rating) nixed from X-RAY ("Radio X", i.e. the radio(telephony spelling alphabet) code for X)
>
>  12. Doomed characters featured in tragedy in Greece (5)
>  **DYING** (doomed) = characters featured in trage(DY IN G)reece
>
>  13. Tech company's info about adversaries (5)
>  **INTEL** ddef: tech company + info about adversaries
>
>  14. Picked up composer's watch (3)
>  **EYE** (watch) = homophone of (picked up, as in, through the ear) I (composer (of the crossword))
>
>  17. Youth organisation for Christian men and other people (4)
>  **THEY** (other people) = THE Y (nickname of YMCA, a youth organisation for Christian men)
>
>  18. Smart programmers have, for decades, used this old programming language, eschewing the predecessor of C (4)
>  **COOL** (smart) = COBOL (programmers have, for decades, used this old programming language), eschewing B (the predecessor of C)
>
>  19. Left-wingers in congress in Riverside, Ca. and Anaheim, Ca. (5)
>  **CIRCA** (ca.) = C_ I_ R_ C_ A_ (left-wingers in "congress ... Ca" and "Anaheim")
>
>  20. Gladys's against power and force of evil (3)
>  **IMP** (force of evil) = I'M (Gladys's) against P (power)

**Down**

> 1. Citizen of EU country discontented – mounting pressure to take to the streets (7)
>  **CYPRIOT** (citizen of EU, which is also a citizen of Cyprus) = C_Y ("country" discontented) mounting P (pressure) RIOT (to take to the streets)
>
>  2. Images of him can be seen all over Egypt, topped with gold and spiritual energy (4)
>  **AURA** (spiritual energy) = RA (Egyptian god, hence "images of him can be seen over Egypt") topped with AU (gold)
>
>  3. Con Air actor John almost has led production to an impasse (3-2-3)
>  **CUL-DE-SAC** (an impasse) = CUSAC(-k) ("Con Air actor John" almost) has LED* production
>
>  4. Short follower of the Church of England embraces English woman (8)
>  **ANGELICA** (woman) = ANGLICA(-n) (short, i.e. deficient/not finished "follower of the Church of England") embracing E (English)
>
>  5. Lone Star State tech company stopped payments? Those are obligatory! (6)
>  **DUTIES** (those are obligatory) = TI (Lone Star State tech company; Texas Instruments) stopped DUES (payments)
>
>  6. State capital, as previously known (3)
>  **EDO** ddef: state (a state of Nigeria) + capital, as previously known (referring to the former name of Tokyo, Japan's capital)
>
>  9. Empty inside, Eddy drinks large cocktail with great appetite (7)
>  **EAGERLY** (with great appetite) = E_Y (empty inside, "Eddy") drinks LARGE* cocktail
>
>  10. Club for introduction to polka, say (6)
>  **PUTTER** (club) = P_ (introduction to polka) + UTTER (say)
>
>  15. Maybe men's moustaches starting to appear in an ominous manner (4)
>  **LOOM** (to appear in an ominous manner) = LOO (maybe "men's", i.e. men's room, or a toilet for men) + M_ (moustaches starting)
>
>  16. Swiss knife peeled twofold letter (3)
>  **CHI** (letter) = CH (Swiss) + (-k)(-n)I(-f)(-e) peeled twofold (outer layers taken twice)

And finally

> Taking the letters that conflict with a Y, we get KUELAP!

Comment: All correct, nice work! 6d is exactly right, and 15d is the right parsing but it's [men's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/men's) (meaning #2).

Comment:  Thanks also for the correction on that last one. Brain lagged that time.