# Tropical Rhythms (Slight Return)

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 30 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

In this crossword, there are no word boundaries. Answers are written one after the other, each sharing at least one letter with the preceding answer. Each row contains one extra “across” clue, whose answer does not fit in the grid.

I really liked my previous destination, so I decided to continue in much of the same vein today. I have taken a tour of a tropical rainforest, admiring the local flora and fauna and taking  a dip in a lovely natural pool deep in the forest. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2etf74ar)

**Across**
7a. *— from Alcatraz*, a film starring Clint Eastwood
7b. — Banks, barrier islands on the US east coast
7c. — code, a collection of criminal laws
7d. Palo —, a city in the Bay Area
7e. *Ænima*, an album by —
8a. "The best — plans of mice and men..."
8b. — Elba, British actor
8c. "Daddy —", another term for father complex
8d. Pacific —, the lands on the edges the Pacific Ocean
8e. There's a Yellow —, Black —, Red — and White — (all actually blue)
9a. —, second person plural in the US south
9b. —, a teacher of Buddhism
9c. —-Strike, a video game by Valve
9d. — river, entrance to the underworld in Greek mythology
10a. Maximum — frequency, a limit on the radio transmission frequency between two given points
10b. Ubiquitous, — present
10c. Recto, the opposite of —
10d. —, an area of New York, London or Hong Kong
10e. Grandfather —, alarm — or cuckoo —
11a. — Nation, a Native American reservation in the Four Corners area
11b. James Earl —, US actor
11c. — Peninsula, a part of Egypt
11d. — guy, a member of the Mafia

**Down**
1a. — people, natives of South Africa and its northern neighbour
1b. Yeas and —, the opposing sides of a vote
1c. —, the nickname of NBA's S. O'Neal
2a. "Sword and —", a genre of films such as *The Last Days of Pompeii*
2b. —, part of the ear or the brain
2c. Joseph Biden III, better known as —
3a. —, strangely frightening
3b. —, a glowing piece of burnt wood
3c. *— v. Wade*, a landmark Supreme Court case
4a. From — to riches
4b. —, the capital of Bolivia
4c. — ahbez, US songwriter
5a. "The shoe is on the — foot"
5b. "— under the bed", communists secretly living in a capitalist society
5c. Two main branches of Islam, Sunni and —
6a. —, animals that pose a threat in the henhouse
6b. — people, natives of South Africa and its inner neighbour
6c. Porridge, also known as — meal

---

Gladys will return in *[Sandwiches by the Seaside](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121627/41973)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining the answers below by user85079, user85080 and user85082 into a single answer:

> The hints not used are Outer, Rim, Counter, Clock, Wise
>
>  [image: Filled grid]

> Reading the outer rim counterclockwise reveals the answer. You are in El Yunque National Forest!

Answer (score 5):

> Could not fit La Paz into column 4
>
>  [image: Filled grid]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling (take the [tour])! You're almost there, one letter is wrong currently.

Answer (score 5):

> The hints not used are Outer, Rim, Counter, Clock, Wise
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNsoq.png

Answer (score 4):

> Reading the outer rim counterclockwise reveals the answer. You are in El Yunque National Forest!

Comment: That's right! By the way did you know you can edit the previous answer so you don't have to post a new one every time? (Assuming that you're the same person that posted the answer above; if not, never mind!)

Comment: @Jafe I think that requires being logged in as the same user (low rep users can only edit their own posts). These posts have different user IDs.

Comment: @fkjx Rats. Maybe I should make a community wiki then? I'd prefer to have everything explained in one answer.