# Where’s the Puzzle?

Tags: knowledge, geography, steganography

<sub>This is part 32 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

Today, I have toured some lovely small lakes in Britain. I have seen Chinese wall paintings depicting balls of fire, heard street singers performing songs from the *Gatsby* musical, and listened to a knowledgeable Dane’s lecture on how to deal with depression. So far the experience has been wonderful.

No, wait. Actually, today I have had to temporarily leave my vehicle by an avenue in New York City to explore the city’s central area. I have looked for amusement on parallel streets and walked south to see some fossils from the Jurassic era. I have also met an actor in Blockbuster and visited Madison Square Garden.

Just kidding. In all seriousness, though, today I have visited a mall in the District of Columbia and spotted many geographic landmarks in the surrounding area. I have met a player representing Washington in the hockey league, and listened to a guard express his identity by singing a Socialist anthem. It’s been a really cool experience for me as a world citizen.

I can’t believe it. That is still not it. Okay, this time for real. I am at a Scandinavian location that you might find in an atlas. Arriving here was a rocky ride, but since I’m a taurus it hasn’t bothered me all that much. Moving around has been a bit of a challenge, especially since there is a superstition in this place that if you take three right turns in a row you have to pour some salt under a table to ward off bad luck. Luckily an Olympic athlete I met earlier has agreed to give me a ride in his Ford Sierra.

Oh no, that wasn’t it either. Today I have visited a huge forested area somewhere east of the Mississippi. I have crossed a historic hiking trail and walked to an overlook spot with magnificent views. I have seen a lot of wildlife including some deer and many different types of birds. I have also passed by numerous waterfalls on my way. There is a lot to explore in this place, actually.

No no no no, silly me. Now I remember. Today I have visited one of the Miracles of the ancient world. The fauna here is like nowhere on Earth. I have seen a talking bear, some kind of cow-horse hybrid, and a war dog from World War II. I also met a mascot representing the “Volunteers”, whatever that means. He and the bandit chasing us got into a fight on top of old… What was it? Oh yes, an old quartz mine. Sorry, my memory of it is still a little hazy.

Can you guess where I really am?

Love, Gladys.

---

Gladys will return in *[An International Affair](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121849/41973)*.

Comment: 32 parts!?!?!?!

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer Out of 81!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Gladys is in:

> [**Great Smoky Mountains National Park**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Smoky_Mountains_National_Park)

To work this out, note that each paragraph (bar one)...

> ...makes lots of references to words or phrases that share a particular one-word connection. In particular, the last word of each paragraph is a literal definition of that connecting word. The one exception is the paragraph referring to the "huge forested area somewhere east of the Mississippi", which is actually a literal description of the target location and its wildlife.

Taking this paragraph by paragraph then... (note that I may not have caught all references, since there are A LOT!)

**Paragraph 1:**

> **GREAT**: Today, I have toured some lovely small [**(GREAT) lakes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Lakes) in [**(GREAT) Britain**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain). I have seen {Chinese wall} [**(GREAT Wall of China)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China) paintings depicting [**(GREAT) balls of fire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Balls_of_Fire), heard street singers performing songs from [**the (GREAT) Gatsby**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Gatsby) musical, and listened to a knowledgeable [**(GREAT) Dane**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Dane)’s lecture on how to deal with [**(GREAT) depression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression). So far the experience has been {wonderful = **GREAT!**}.

**Paragraph 2:**

> **PARK:** No, wait. Actually, today I have had to {temporarily leave my vehicle} **(PARK)** by {an avenue in New York City} [**(PARK Avenue)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Avenue) to explore {the city’s central area} [**(Central PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Park). I have looked for [**amusement (PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amusement_park) on [**parallel (PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_parking) streets and walked [**south (PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park) to see some fossils from the [**Jurassic (PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park) era. I have also met {an actor in [Blockbuster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockbuster_(TV_series))} [**(Randall PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_Park) and visited [**Madison Square (PARK)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madison_Square_and_Madison_Square_Park) {Garden = **PARK!**}.

**Paragraph 3:**

> **NATIONAL:** Just kidding. In all seriousness, though, today I have visited {a mall in the District of Columbia} [**(NATIONAL) Mall**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Mall) and spotted many [**(NATIONAL) geographic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Geographic) landmarks in the surrounding area. I have met {a player representing Washington} [**(Washington NATIONAL(S))**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Nationals) in the [**(NATIONAL) hockey league**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Hockey_League), and listened to a [**(NATIONAL) guard**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Guard) [**(NATIONAL) express**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Express_Coaches) his **(NATIONAL) identity** by singing a [**(NATIONAL) Socialist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazism) **(NATIONAL) anthem**. It’s been a really cool experience for me as a world {citizen = **NATIONAL!**}.

**Paragraph 4:**

> **MOUNTAINS:** I can’t believe it. That is still not it. Okay, this time for real. I am at a [**Scandinavian (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_Mountains) location that you might find in an [**atlas (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_Mountains). Arriving here was a [**rocky (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Mountains) ride, but since I’m a [**taurus (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurus_Mountains) it hasn’t bothered me all that much. **Moving (MOUNTAINS)** around has been a bit of a challenge, especially since there is a [**superstition (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstition_Mountains) in this place that if you take three right turns in a row you have to pour some [**salt (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_Range) under a [**table (MOUNTAIN(S))**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_Mountain) to ward off [**bad luck (MOUNTAIN(S))**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Luck_Mountain). Luckily an [**Olympic (MOUNTAINS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Mountains) athlete I met earlier has agreed to give me a ride in his Ford {Sierra = **MOUNTAINS!**}.

**Paragraph 5:**

> **Definition of the target location:** Oh no, that wasn’t it either. Today I have visited a huge forested area somewhere east of the Mississippi. I have crossed a historic hiking trail and walked to an overlook spot with magnificent views. I have seen a lot of wildlife including some deer and many different types of birds. I have also passed by numerous waterfalls on my way. There is a lot to explore in this place, actually.

**Paragraph 6:**

> **SMOKY/SMOKEY:** No no no no, silly me. Now I remember. Today I have visited {one of [the Miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miracles)} **(SMOKEY Robinson)** of the ancient world. The fauna here is like nowhere on Earth. I have seen {a talking bear} **([SMOKEY Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokey_Bear))**, {some kind of cow-horse hybrid} **([SMOKY the Cowhorse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoky_the_Cowhorse))**, and {a war dog from World War II} **([SMOKY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoky_(dog)))**. I also met {a mascot representing the “Volunteers”} **([SMOKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokey_(mascot)))**, whatever that means. He [**(SMOKEY) and the bandit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokey_and_the_Bandit) chasing us got into a fight [**on top of old… (SMOKEY)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Top_of_Old_Smoky) What was it? Oh yes, an old [**(SMOKY) quartz**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoky_quartz) mine. Sorry, my memory of it is still a little {hazy = **SMOKY!**}.

All that remains is to rearrange the discovered words...

> ...and we have GREAT SMOKY MOUNTAINS NATIONAL PARK!