# An International Affair

Tags: knowledge, geography, codeword

<sub>This is part 33 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

This is a codeword puzzle. Each of the numbers 1–26 stands for a different letter A–Z. Find the correct values for each number so that every entry in the grid makes an existing word found in the UK Advanced Cryptics Dictionary.<sup>1</sup> Letters outside the grid are not part of the codeword and are only there to help you find the final answer in the end.

Today I have visited twin cities straddling an international border in an extremely photogenic place. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty codeword grid]

[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2yebff8a) (use the "Number" tool)

<sup>1</sup> UKACD: [download](http://cfajohnson.com/wordfinder/UKACD17.shtml) , [search](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=&ent=Search&dict=0)

---

Gladys will return in *[Campfire Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121959/41973)*.

Comment: @msh210 Try click on "number". Worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, the wrong mode was selected there. Sorry about that! I'm still finding new ways to fail with Penpa, apparently.

Comment: Can't fix the Penpa link without recreating it from scratch, so I've added a side note to use the number tool for now.

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a charm.  Doesn't autofill guesses, though, which is what I expected.  Anyway, I meanwhile solved it in an image editor. _shrug_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I used Qat (linked in the question). Only one word fits the pattern of the middle vertical (the one that turns out to be *assassins*) and after that things fell into place.
> [image]

> If you then take the Mth square in the column marked M (starting from that direction), and so on, all [modulo 13](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), you get a set of twelve letters that anagram to *Niagara Falls*.
> [image]