# Campfire Crossword

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords, mazes, printers-devilry

<sub>This is part 34 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

These are printer’s devilry clues with an additional definition part in each clue. However, please read on because the rules are a bit different than last time! In each clue, you must find a word which can be inserted somewhere into the clue (possibly changing spacing, punctuation and capitalisation but not the order of letters) so that the whole sentence makes sense. In addition, each clue contains, either at the start or end of the clue, a straight crossword definition for the answer of one of the *other* clues. Enumerations refer to the answer of each clue, not to the answer which the definition part points at. For example, if the answer to clue #5 was FIFTH and the answer to clue #2 was SECOND, clue #5 might start with something like “A measure of time...” (defining the word “second”) and have the enumeration (5) (because “fifth” is five letters long). I hope that makes sense!

Today I have enjoyed the great outdoors. I have trekked deep into the wilderness, had coffee at a campfire and seen moose, bison and beavers in an amazing natural environment. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/24vfhgcb)

1. He fly a little bit tipsy after drinking a number of beers (5)
2. To make systematic progress, the company had town E between innovation and satisfying their existing customers (6)
3. According to my friend LeCross, in London is at a location that's very accessible (7)
4. Man credited with splitting the AI? Sh! Lyre warded by the French head of state (8)
5. When the rest of the group sleeps in a ho, TNT outside that's already becoming damp (9)
6. Back in the day, the Scandinavians has and crosses was what they called tic-tac-toe in Australia (11)
7. Ticket resellers told us the most recorded jazz'd ward (hey, man!) and Johnny Green's "Body and Soul" (11)
8. In DJ, I, boss, Ed the local navy by spraying holy water on a warship (10)
9. The content of the band's first deen IOUs compositions – I cannot name a single one to get rid of (10)
10. To provoke discussion, they proposed a new method for telling different isotopes of car, nab ling scientists to more reliably determine the age of objects (9)
11. John, the musician, claims to have a serious personality, but I think he, Sara on ally (8)
12. The member of seal teamed a box lunch at the base (3-4)
13. The King of Croatia used to confiscate one firey (6)
14. Fleet Street was full of cared illegally this morning (5)

---

Gladys will return in *[It Must Be New York](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122024/41973)*.

Comment: Has Gladys recently been more fond of National Parks than before?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Props to msh210 for finishing off the clues before I could - go upvote [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121961/77182).

A full explanation of the clues:

> 1. He f**ELT ON**ly a little bit tipsy after drinking *a number of beers* (5) - def: "John, the musician" (11)
>  2. *To make systematic* progress, the company had to w**ALK A LI**ne between innovation and satisfying their existing customers (6) - def: "base" (12)
>  3. According to my friend Le**VI, KING'S** Cross in London is at a location that's very *accessible* (7) - def: "Back in the day, the Scandinavians" (6)
>  4. Man credited with splitting the a**TOM IS LAV**ishly rewarded by the *French head of state* (8) - def: "The King of Croatia" (13)
>  5. When the rest of the group sleeps in a hot**EL, I'M IN A TE**nt outside that's already *becoming damp* (9) - def: "to get rid of" (9)
>  6. *Back in the day, the Scandinavians* ha**D READ NOUGHT**s and crosses was what they called tic-tac-toe in Australia (11) - def: "warship" (8)
>  7. *Ticket resellers* told us the most recorded jazz **STANDARD IS E**dward Heyman and Johnny Green's "Body and Soul" (11) - def: "To make systematic" (2)
>  8. In Djibo**UTI, LISA BLE**ssed the local navy by spraying holy water on a *warship* (10) - def: "accessible" (3)
>  9. The content of the band's first de**MO IS TEN ING**enious compositions – I cannot name a single one *to get rid of* (10) - def: "becoming damp" (5)
>  10. *To provoke discussion*, they proposed a new method for telling different isotopes of car**BON APART, E**nabling scientists to more reliably determine the age of objects (9) - def: "French head of state" (4)
>  11. *John, the musician*, claims to have a serious personality, but I think he's a ra**SCAL, PERS**onally (8) - def: "Ticket resellers" (7)
>  12. The member of SEAL Team **SIX PACK**ed a box lunch at the *base* (3-4) - def: "a number of beers" (1)
>  13. *The King of Croatia* used to confiscate one fire**ARM A DA**y (6) - def: "Fleet" (14)
>  14. *Fleet* Street was full of car**S PARK**ed illegally this morning (5) - def: "To provoke discussion" (10)

Now, to find Gladys, notice that

> each clue shares exactly one letter with the clue above it, and one letter with the clue below it:
>
>  [image: the grid, with shared letters highlighted]

If we then

> trace a path through the grid, as indicated by the entry and exit arrows, and traveling on each clue between the shared letters, we get our answer:
>
>  [image: the grid again, with the path highlighted]

Therefore, Gladys is in

> **ELK ISLAND NATIONAL PARK**!

Answer (score 12):

> [image]

That is,

> 1. He f**elt on**ly a little bit tipsy after drinking a number of beers
> 2. To make systematic progress, the company had to w**alk a li**ne between innovation and satisfying their existing customers
> 3. According to my friend Le**vi, Kings** Cross in London is at a location that's very accessible
> 4. Man credited with splitting the a**tom is lav**ishly rewarded by the French head of state
> 5. When the rest of the group sleeps in a hot**el, I'm in a te**nt outside that's already becoming damp
> 6. Back in the day, the Scandinavians ha**d read, nought**s and crosses was what they called tic-tac-toe in Australia
> 7. Ticket resellers told us the most recorded jazz **standard is E**dward Heyman and Johnny Green's "Body and Soul"
> 8. In Djibo**uti, Lisa ble**ssed the local navy by spraying holy water on a warship
> 9. The content of the band's first de**mo is ten ing**enious compositions – I cannot name a single one to get rid of
> 10. To provoke discussion, they proposed a new method for telling different isotopes of car**bon apart, e**nabling scientists to more reliably determine the age of objects
> 11. John, the musician, claims to have a serious personality, but I think he's a ra**scal, pers**onally
> 12. The member of Seal Team **Six pack**ed a box lunch at the base
> 13. The King of Croatia used to confiscate one fire**arm a da**y
> 14. Fleet Street was full of car**s park**ed illegally this morning

And then

> a word-search-style path through the grid from arrow to arrow yields [*Elk Island National Park*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elk_Island_National_Park). But [juicifer's answer](/a/121962) has a better explanation for how to find this: it's not just word-search-style, but… well, go check out and upvote his answer.

Comment: Can you explain the clues?

Comment: @newQOpenWid good now?