# It Must Be New York

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 35 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

In this crossword, whenever one or more letters from the start of the clue form a substring of the answer, those letters must be highlighted in the grid. For example, if the clue starts “On Tuesday...” and the answer is MONTAGE, highlight the letters ONT of the answer in the grid. Or, if the clue starts "Without..." and the answer is SHOWER, highlight the letter W of the answer in the grid. Use different colours for “across” and “down” answers.

Today, I am at a lovely small town that’s probably best known for a relatively short boom over a century ago. However, even now this place has a lot to offer to visitors, both in the surrounding nature and the town itself. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/24e58ro8)

**Across**
1. Chilled
5. What one hunts in order to eat "long pig"
8. Individual doing supporting work; an assistant
9. Before, poetically
10. Haemorrhage
12. Chimay Bleue, say
13. (*Of cities*) Like York, Dubrovnik and the Vatican but unlike Los Angeles
15. Thrown, stumped (*3 wds.*)
17. Golfer Gary (or any other golfer, technically)
18. Scott Joplin composition, perhaps
19. Year 2004 presidential candidate
23. Genre of The Get Up Kids
24. Polynesian island
25. That there
26. Mses Kravitz and Saldaña, say

**Down**
1. Jazzman Calloway
2. What Norway has in large quantities but Sweden does not
3. Lyric poem
4. Wiggle room
5. Afternoon tea and supper, for example
6. Southern French city
7. Requirement, demand
11. *Doctor Who* cyborg
14. Songwriter Hart
15. Place remembered in Texas
16. (*On entering public transport*) Show travel card to reader (*2 wds.*)
17. An antelope to a leopard, say
20. Animated film featuring parrots
21. Sorely regret
22. British prog rock group

---

Gladys will return in *[Roughing It (Once More)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122073/41973)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gladys seems to be in

> **Dawson City, Yukon, CA**

Completed crossword grid:

> [image: completed crossword grid]
>  I have marked all letters **green** for the corresponding letters *across*. All letters **red** for the corresponding letters *down*.

> *"probably best known for a relatively short boom over a century ago"* -> [Klondike Gold Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_Gold_Rush)

Comment: Can you explain the puzzle title "It Must Be New York"?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I have seriously no idea. Maybe Jafe can give a hint about that?

Comment: @SkySpiral7 Sorry, yeah, that ended up being unnecessarily obscure. The idea was to mimic the style of NYT crosswords. But I suppose there are a bunch of publications that use the symmetrical fully-checked grid format so that reference doesn't actually work all that well. It's weirdly hard sometimes to come up with good titles!

Comment: @Jafe, haha, At first I thought that the final answer was supposed to be in New York, and I have looked quite some time to find something in NY with the name Dawson. I couldn't fould anything, only The Dawson restaurant :)