# Around the Bend in Many Steps

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords

<sub>This is part 38 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

This is an Around-the-Bend puzzle. Each answer occupies two rows of the grid, overlapping with the answer immediately below. Each answer starts on its numbered row (but not necessarily its first cell), goes left-to-right until the end of the row, picks up one given letter from the rightmost column, and then turns around and continues right-to-left on the next row. Answers on each row must use the white cell and can use any number of the light grey cells provided.

Today, I have visited a beautiful religious site that was built over a thousand years ago. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty Around-the-Bend grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2b92eql7)

1. Rear end
2. Official decrees
3. What powered Watt's engine
4. It has two poles
5. Achilles –, part of the human heel
6. Cosa –, the mafia
7. Architectural style of the Empire State Building (*2 wds.*)
8. Pelagic
9. Film theatres
10. Brazilian compositions
11. Nordic shvitz
12. Stranger to granters, for example
13. Model and actress Hemingway

---

Gladys will return in *[Before the Common Era](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122399/41973)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gladys is visiting:

> The **[Kitano Tenmangū](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitano_Tenmang%C5%AB)** shrine in Japan.

The completed grid:

> [image]

The clues:

> 1. Rear end - **BACKSIDE**
>  2. Official decrees - **EDICTS**
>  3. What powered Watt's engine - **STEAM**
>  4. It has two poles - **MAGNET**
>  5. Achilles –, part of the human heel - **TENDON**
>  6. Cosa –, the mafia - **NOSTRA**
>  7. Architectural style of the Empire State Building (2 wds.) - **ART DECO**
>  8. Pelagic - **OCEANIC**
>  9. Film theatres - **CINEMAS**
>  10. Brazilian compositions - **SAMBAS**
>  11. Nordic shvitz - **SAUNA**
>  12. Stranger to granters, for example - **ANAGRAM**
>  13. Model and actress Hemingway - **MARGAUX**