# Before the Common Era

Tags: knowledge, calculation-puzzle, grid-deduction, geography, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This is part 39 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

The grid on the left-hand side is a KenKen puzzle. Fill the grid so that every row and column contains the digits 1–7 once each. Each box, marked with bold lines, has a number and a mathematical operator in the upper-left corner. The number indicates the result of the operation combining the digits inside the box with the given operator. For example, 10+ in the upper-left corner means that the digits inside the box sum to 10. Digits can repeat inside a box (as long as they’re on different rows and columns).

The right-hand side grid is a cryptic crossword. The answers to eleven clues are too long to fit in the grid. In these cases, one or two letters must be left out from either the start or end of the answer, making a new, real word found in the UKACD. Enumerations refer to the length of the word *after* shortening (in other words, the length of the space available in the grid). Highlight one or two letters of the clue in same the position as the dropped letters in the answer (i.e. either the first letter, first two letters, the last letter or last two letters). The highlighted letters, in clue order, reveal how to find two words in the grid which form the final answer.

Today I have visited a site that displays remnants of a culture from even further back than my last stop, well before the Common Era. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty KenKen and crossword grids]
[KenKen on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yrown854)
[Crossword on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yvdsozsd)

**Across**
2. Drug (e.g. ground beef) (6)
6. Captures on film the sound of nocturnal flyer interrupting couple in Montparnasse (4)
8. Before the Common Era, Levantine leader met with resistance infiltrating western country, showing corrupting influences (6)
10. Vacant attic here about to be abandoned for long (3)
12. Cannabis and ecstasy taken by Hungary's foremost representative (3)
13. Sea shells in arcade game action (6)
15. Number of magic users (that is, five) being held hostage by filmmaking brother? (4)
16. Shoes made out of leather of British grouse, surprisingly (6)

**Down**
1. An object in the household that's stranger than cars (6)
3. Dinosaur's tail sliced European member of the working class (4)
4. Practices helping make freddo espresso (3)
5. Candidate who warned about impending disaster and bloodshed (4)
7. Most don't unendingly upset Marie or Donny? (6)
9. MI6 employee uttered suggestion (3)
11. Wetland dweller; he's supported by silver-screen anchorman (4)
12. Having penetrated female on farm, Victor is after a safe place (4)
14. Crazy good action game: *Arkham Origins* (3)

---

Gladys will return in *[Regional Business](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122471/41973)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The crossword and KenKen can be solved like so:

> [image]

The highlighted letters read

> SEVENS AND ONES

Reading

> the letters on the crossword corresponding to sevens and ones on the KenKen,

we find that Gladys is at

> the GOCHANG DOLMENS!
>  [image]