# E Rebus Unum – a picture sequence puzzle

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, geography, sequence

<sub>This is part 42 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

Today I have been taking it easy. You might even say it has been a walk in the park! I have admired a large, peaceful green area in the centre of a city which is famous for such areas. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Rebus puzzle with 19 squares]
<sub>Image licences: Public domain *except*

Top row #2, bottom silhouette: **Alice-astro**, CC BY-SA 3.0

Top row #6, bottom right corner: **Bastianow** & **Themightyquill**, CC BY-SA 4.0

Middle row #7, photo: **Paul Cush**, CC BY 3.0</sub>

---

Gladys will return in *[Symmetries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122882/41973)*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gladys is in:

> the [**Humble Administrator's Garden**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humble_Administrator%27s_Garden) in Suzhou.

The three rows of rebuses can be solved as follows:

**Top row:**

> CHASTE = [CHAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chas_%26_Dave) + [T.E.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._E._Lawrence)
>  TEMPERATE = [TEMPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempeh) + RAT + E
>  CHARITABLE = [CHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_tea) + [RITA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rita_Hayworth) + BLE
>  DILIGENT = (IL ID)< + GENT
>  KIND = K IN D
>  PATIENT = TIE in PANT(-s)
>
>  These are adjectives referring to the first six of the **[seven capital virtues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_virtues)** in Christianity. The seventh would be **HUMBLE**.

**Middle row:**

> OPERATORS = [OPERA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Opera_House) + TORS (days of the week in Danish)
>  MENTORS = [ENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebeard) in MORS(-e) (The Morse code characters spell 'THIS CODE'; 80% of MORSE is MORS.)
>  ENTERTAINERS = [ENTERTAINER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Entertainer_(rag)) + S ([maritime signal flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags))
>  ENGINEERS = ENGINEER (this word can follow all of the others) + S (in Braille)
>  COORDINATORS = [COOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coors_Brewing_Company) + [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana,_Princess_of_Wales) + [NATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO) + RS
>  CONSERVATORS = [CONSERVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservapedia) + T + [OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate)S
>  ADVOCATES = [ADVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bad_Voodoo_Daddy) + [CATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cate_Blanchett)S
>
>  These are seven of the eight temperaments in the [Keirsey Temperament Sorter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keirsey_Temperament_Sorter) - the eighth is **ADMINISTRATORS**.

**Bottom row:**

> These all form [nicknames of US states](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_nicknames) going down the eastern coastline:
>
>  Maine: PINE TREE = ETRE in PI+NE
>  New Hampshire: GRANITE = G ([metrix prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) initials missing 'G' for 'giga') + [RA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra) + (-u)NITE
>  Massachusetts: BAY = [BAY(-er)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer)
>  Rhode Island: [OCEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean%27s_Eleven)
>  Connecticut: [CONSTITUTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States)
>  New York: EMPIRE = MP in [EIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland)
>
>  The next state along the coast is New Jersey, whose nickname is the **GARDEN** state.

Putting these all together gives us:

> HUMBLE ADMINISTRATORS GARDEN, which clearly leads us to [this place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humble_Administrator%27s_Garden) fitting the description.

Comment: Did you do reverse image on the tempe there? Or do you already know what it is?

Comment: @justhalf Actually, I worked out the other ones in that row first, then was left with ...RATE at the end and retrospectively worked out which element was missing and so what it must be. Briefly searching that term in Google showed me enough images that I figured this was correct (though I couldn't spot the exact one... It turns out that one is buried deep within the Wikipedia page itself).

Comment: Ah, cool! As an Indonesian I confirm that it is a tempe. 