# Escape from a Grand Canyon

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, geography

<sub>This is part 44 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

Can you help me out here? I am trapped inside a small room that’s locked from the outside. There is a keypad next to the door, but I don’t know the combination.

[image: Keypad with coloured digits 0-9.]

There is some kind of instruction sheet taped next to it, but the text looks like gibberish to me.

> Elvetway igitsday. Indfay edray eykay, enthay ueblay eykay, ellowyay eykay, enthay eengray eykay.

I’ll try to explain what I see around me so you can help me out. There are two pictures on one wall.

[image: Two pictures on the wall: Painting of man shouting, and a black-and-white photo of a bearded man sitting.]

There’s a table in one corner with what looks like a card game going on. I tried to pick up the cards to inspect them, but they seem to be permanently glued to the table.

[image: Picture of card game on table.]

There's another picture on the other wall.

[image: Picture on the wall: Two people dancing on the street.]
<sup>Image credit: Manticora87, CC BY-SA 4.0.</sup>

There’s a bookshelf with nine books on one wall. Again, can’t pick up the books as they are glued in place.

[image: Bookshelf with nine book titles: Clare: City of Bones, Dashner: The Kill Order, Riordan: The Sea of Monsters, Paolini: Eldest, Vaughn: Kitty and the Midnight Hour, Meyer: Breaking Dawn, Gabaldon: Voyager, Collins: Mockingjay, and Pullman: The Subtle Knife.]

One more picture on the opposite wall.

[image: Picture of a city square lined with palm trees.]
<sup>Image credit: Pitxiquin, CC BY-SA 4.0.</sup>

One wall is just covered in these strange characters.

[image: Wall filled with rectangular characters.]

And finally a couple more pictures on the walls. I have no idea what any of this means. Help!

[image: Two pictures on the wall. Black-and-white photo of a man in a bowler hat smiling, and a black-and-white painting of a man with sword leaning onto a wall.]

Just kidding. Of course, I haven’t actually been trapped inside for the entire day. In fact, you can be sure that I have got plenty of fresh air! Today I have taken a tour of a national park surrounding a massive canyon. Using the clues I’ve given you, can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

---

Gladys will return in *[Turn Back the Clocks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123443/41973)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Overall Solution

The Pig Latin clue tells us we have 12 digits and also gives us 4 more instructions:

> Red Key was written in Romanian.
>  The Romanian flag is blue, yellow red 
>
>  Blue Key was written in Italian.
>  The Italian flag is green, white, red 
>
>  Yellow Key was written in Irish.
>  The Irish flag is green, white and orange 
>
>  Green Key was written in French.
>  The French flag is blue, white and red

Let's tap those colour keys in the order we can see in the spoiler above. We get:

> [TAROKO GORGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taroko_National_Park) 
>  So long as we discount a letter once it has been used (Thanks M Oehm!)

---

#### Partial solutions:

---

##### Pig Latin

> Elvetway igitsday. Indfay edray eykay, enthay ueblay eykay, ellowyay eykay, enthay eengray eykay.

This is just [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) and resolves to:

> Twelve digits. Find red key, then blue key, yellow key, then green key.

---

##### Picture Clues

There are greek letters overlaid on the pictures.

In the first picture

- the left is [l'**Echo**](https://artgallery.yale.edu/collections/objects/34000),  Bathers at Asnières by Georges Seurat
- I see Epsilon (5th), Gamma(3rd) and Theta(8th) on the left
- the right is **Victor** Hugo.
- I see Delta(4th) on the right

In the second picture of **Tango** Dancers

- I see the letter Ita(7th)

In the third picture

- This is the government palace of Peru in **Lima**
- I see the letter beta(2nd)

In the fourth picture

- The left is **Charlie** Chaplin
- I see the letter alpha(1st)
- The right is a representation of **Romeo** from Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet.
- I see the letter zeta(6th)

> The images all depict codewords in the NATO phonetic alphabet, the Greek letters provide an ordering for them. So we have: CHARLIE, LIMA, ECHO, VICTOR, ECHO, ROMEO, TANGO, ECHO which spells CLÉ VERTE (i.e. GREEN KEY)

---

##### Uno

Following the rule of Uno and starting at with the bottom player, playing in the direction of the arrow we play:

> ```
>  green 3 - C
>  green 7 - H
>  blue 7  - E
>  blue >< - I
>  red ><  - E
>  red x   - R
>  red 2   - O (UNO!)
>  yellow 2- S
>  yellow+2- I
>  yellow 4- E
>  Game over
> ```

> CHEIE ROSIE - (Red Key in Romanian)

---

##### Books

The books are each one of a series. Taking the series number of the book and selecting that letter from the author's name gives

> chiave blu (Blue Key in Italian)

---

##### "Strange Characters"

This is the [Pigpen Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher). It resolves to:

> ```
>  E    E   Z   N   A   P   M   I   H   C
>  D    A   E   H   R   E   P   P   O   C
>  E    U   O   B   I   R   A   C   H   R
>  C    O   U   G   A   R   K   A   O   O
>  H    A   C   H   N   A   M   I   A   C
>  I    R   H   A   T   E   E   H   C   O
>  C    B   A   O   L   I   R   W   A   D
>  K    O   O   E   B   H   U   O   M   I
>  E    C   O   Y   O   T   E   R   E   L
>  N    N   I   I   T   A   O   C   L   E
> ```

Which I thought was going to be another cipher, but surpisingly I found it was a

> Wordsearch featuring animals - all of which appear to begin with the letter C. I've found:
>  [image]

The remainder spells out

> eochair bhuí
>  which is "Yellow Key" in Irish Gaelic

Some credit to share here with Stiv and M Oehm!

Comment: There's quite a few more to spot in that bottom spoiler - I can see rot13(PNVZNA, PBPXNGBB, PURRGNU, PBBG naq PBNGV) as well...

Comment: Updated thanks! PBBG I think is coincidence however,

Comment: Also, rot13(Gur vzntrf nyy qrcvpg pbqrjbeqf va gur ANGB cubargvp nycunorg, gur Terrx yrggref cebivqr na beqrevat sbe gurz. Fb jr unir: PUNEYVR, YVZN, ([RPUB](https://artgallery.yale.edu/collections/objects/34000)), IVPGBE, (RPUB), EBZRB, GNATB, (RPUB) juvpu fcryyf PYR IREGR (v.r. TERRA XRL)) Oh, and re the Uno game, rot13(purv vebfvr vf Terrx sbe UR UNF N UREB) - may prove useful :)

Comment: Unfortunately, today is a working day for me so my presence is fleeting right now but two more pointers for you: rot13(Ybbx hc gubfr yrsgbire jbeqfrnepu yrggref va Vevfu, naq abgr gung nyy gubfr obbxf ner bar bs n frevrf, juvpu fubhyq or hfrshy...) Good luck!

Comment: I'm embarrassed I didn't spot the pattern for pictures! :D Updated again thanks.
I'm not so convinced by the uno solution however. That's not a great translation, at least in modern Terrx where it would be `echei iros`(no cipher, just anglicised Terrx) .

Comment: Nice progress so far! You have a small transcription error in the Uno section (there's no red card with 'i').

Comment: Indeed I do! Thanks. That's helped.

Comment: The word is not Greek, but rot13(purvr ebf̧vr, "erq xrl" va Ebznvana, n ynathntr fcbxra va n pbhagel jvgu nabgure iregpny gevpbybhe). (Fun puzzle and impressive progress.)

Comment: You are on the right track, but rot13(cerffvt n xrl "hfrf hc" gur yrsgzbfg flzoby).

Comment: And there's the full solution :) Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: I'm confused as to how you get from the keys to the final answer. What does it mean to "tap those colour keys in the order ... in the spoiler"? EDIT: OH never mind it's based on rot13(gur pbhagevrf' syntf)! I think you should add that to this answer XD

Comment: @samm82 they're in the first spoiler but they aren't rendering properly on my computer so I was confused too

Comment: Ah if rendering is a problem I'll add more info