# Breathe, breathe in the air

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords, jigsaw-puzzle

<sub>This is part 47 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

This time I have a jigsaw puzzle for you. You need to first solve a crossword, and after that fill all white cells with the given pieces. Pieces must be inserted as is (no rotating or mirroring), and letters on pieces must match the filled crossword grid.

Today I have breathed in the smoky air on the slopes of a very active volcano. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](http://tinyurl.com/ypctmt66)

**Across**
1. Speak
3. To me (2,2,7)
9. Breathe (in the air)
10. On the run (2,5)
12. Time
14. The great (4,2,4)
19. Gig
22. In the sky
24. Money
25. Us and them
29. Any
31. Colour
33. You
36. Like
38. Brain damage
39. Eclipse

**Down**
1. Small, insignificant
2. British prog group
3. Egyptian deity or Levantine self-proclaimed Caliphate (*abbr.*)
4. *The Simpsons* bartender
5. Pythia, for one
6. Unwell
7. What comes after E in the Queen's monogram (2,1)
8. Originally known as
11. Precious stone
13. Flee
15. Broadcasts (a show)
16. Instrument used in bloodletting
17. First adjective used to describe Frankenstein's monster
18. Slippery swimmer
20. Warren Buffett, the "Oracle of –"
21. Lists as a source
23. Beheaded queen
24. Sequel game to *The Frozen Throne* (*abbr.*)
26. Interconnected smart devices (*abbr.*)
27. More strained
28. Nonsense word from *The Shining* (or is it?)
30. *Game of Thrones* network (*abbr.*)
32. Novel by Jane Austen
33. What's not visible on the dark side of the Moon
34. Musician Reed
35. Part of the self
36. Old French coin
37. Young man

---

Gladys will return in *[Wreck Exploration](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124766/41973)*.

Comment: Loving the Pink Floyd clues!

Comment: @0x5453 Hehe, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gladys is

> on Mount Yasur, on Tanna Island, Vanuatu.

Completed grid with puzzle pieces:

> [image]