# Winetasting Far from Home

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords, mazes

<sub>This is part 51 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

I hope you are well. My journey continues with another exciting destination. Today I have toured some lovely small towns that form an impressive wine-growing region. The culture in the area is quite distinct and has an interesting European influence. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty crossword grid]
<sup>Colouring note: In the three groups of cells on the right-hand side of the image, the line going through the first group of cells is green and the lines in the bottom two groups are red.</sup>
[Solve on Penpa+](http://tinyurl.com/ypf396da)

**Across**
1. The S in PSE
5. Mos —, former stage name of rapper Yasiin Bey
7. Like B, M or P, phonetically
9. Go down a black diamond, perhaps
10. A Friend
11. Mystical life force
13. The first letter in Heraklion
15. Spurs supporters
18. E.g. MIT
20. An edible part of a lobster
21. The score at the start of overtime
22. — Moon, drummer of the Who

**Down**
2. Yugoslav leader
3. The Matterhorn, for example
4. African staple food
5. Satellite receiver
6. Maya the Bee's grasshopper friend
7. Lawyers' association
8. — Thieves, 1940s film classic
12. Mongrel
14. Magazine that selects the "Person of the Year"
16. Legislative assembly
17. Babe's home?
19. — Lilly, US pharmaceutical company

---

Gladys will return in *[Aquatic Giants](/q/125221/41973)*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Gladys is visiting...

> ...the **[Barossa Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barossa_Valley)**, an area in South Australia with strong European heritage, renowned for producing wine.

The crossword solves as follows:

> [image: Solved crossword]

The final answer can be read off according to the rules specified to the right of the grid:

> By drawing a line from letter to letter between the 'in' and 'out' arrows, without passing through solid walls or a letter 'I':
>
>  [image: Answer trace in grid]
>
>  In fact, it's worth pointing out here that the crossword entries have clearly been specifically chosen so that there are 'I's positioned throughout the grid in such a way that there is *only one possible route* through the maze, without doubling-back on oneself at any point. This can be seen effectively by adding additional walls (here marked with crosses) around any cell containing an 'I':
>
>  [image: Answer trace in grid, with additional walls to block access to any 'I' cell, to illustrate the maze in full]

Clue explanations:

> **Across**
>  1. The S in PSE = **STACK**
>  5. Mos —, former stage name of rapper Yasiin Bey = **[DEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasiin_Bey)**
>  7. Like B, M or P, phonetically = **[BILABIAL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilabial)** (produced with both lips)
>  9. Go down a black diamond, perhaps = **[SKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste#Ratings)** (ski slope difficulty indication)
>  10. A Friend = **[ROSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Geller)**
>  11. Mystical life force = **CHI**
>  13. The first letter in Heraklion = **ETA** (the first letter in the native Greek spelling of '[Heraklion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraklion)': Ηράκλειο)
>  15. Spurs supporters = **[YIDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tottenham_Hotspur_F.C._supporters#Jewish_association)**
>  18. E.g. MIT = **UNI**(versity)
>  20. An edible part of a lobster = **[TOMALLEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomalley)**
>  21. The score at the start of overtime = **TIE**
>  22. — Moon, drummer of the Who = **[KEITH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Moon)**
>
>  **Down**
>  2. Yugoslav leader = **[TITO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josip_Broz_Tito)**
>  3. The Matterhorn, for example = **[ALP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matterhorn)**
>  4. African staple food = **[CASSAVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassava)**
>  5. Satellite receiver = **DISH**
>  6. Maya the Bee's grasshopper friend = **[FLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_the_Bee#Main_characters)**
>  7. Lawyers' association = **[BAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(law))**
>  8. — Thieves, 1940s film classic = **[BICYCLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_Thieves)**
>  12. Mongrel = **MUTT**
>  14. Magazine that selects the "Person of the Year" = **[TIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(magazine))**
>  16. Legislative assembly = **[DIET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_(assembly))**
>  17. Babe's home? = **[STY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babe_(film))** (Babe is a pig)
>  19. — Lilly, US pharmaceutical company = **[ELI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eli_Lilly_and_Company)**