# Mercury in Centigrade

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, grid-deduction, geography, sudoku

<sub>This is part 55 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

This is a non-consecutive thermo sudoku. Fill the grid so that each row, column and 3x3 contains the digits 1–9 once each. Cells sharing an edge may not contain consecutive digits. Just like mercury rises in actual therometers, so too must the numbers in sudoku thermometers strictly increase from the bulb end. The final answer is given by the highlighted numbers, none of which are actually mercury.

Today I have visited a traditional settlement built over water. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Empty sudoku grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](http://tinyurl.com/29lo6z2x)

---

Gladys will return in *[Burial Traditions](/q/125872/41973)*.

Comment: "Digits separated by a white dot are consecutive. All possible white dots are given." :P

Comment: This is the first SE puzzle I could actually solve (although I had to google the final answer because I have not heard of that before)

Comment: @Féileacán That's awesome to hear! Congrats! I don't think I had heard of the answer either, before scouring travel sites for cool places to include here :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solved sudoku looks like this:

> [image: Solved sudoku]

The key to start the sudoku is

> realizing that the following two thermometers are uniquely determined by the non-consecutive rule and increasing rule.
>
>  [image: keypoint]

From here it is easy to solve the rest.

After solving the sudoku,

> we extract the underlined numbers and find the relevant elements in the periodic table, as hinted by '*none of which are actual mercury*'.
>
>
>  19- Potassium (**K**)
>  95- Americium (**Am**)
>  15- Phosphorous (**P**)
>  8 - Oxygen (**O**)
>  7 - Nitrogen (**N**)
>  31- Gallium (**Ga**)
>  39- Yttrium (**Y**)
>  68- Erbium (**Er**)

So Gladys is visiting

> [**Kampong Ayer**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kampong_Ayer), a traditional settlement in Brunei.